# Sata Port failing?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sata

I have a [Samsung 350V5C](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-350V5C-15-6-inch-Laptop-Silver/dp/B009SJCX5Y) laptop running Windows 8.1. About 1.5 years ago I replaced the main drive with an SSD (for the C: drive) and replaced the optical drive with a [HDD caddy](http://hddcaddy.eu/) and a 1TB HDD (for data storage). This worked fine for about a year.

Earlier this year, I found that the laptop would become very slow suddenly which sometimes forcing me to hard-reboot it. When it booted up again the data-drive was no longer showing up (not even in disk management). The only way to fix this was to physically unplug the drive, reboot the pc, shutdown, plug in the drive and reboot. This happened periodically for a while. Sometimes I would just boot up the PC and the problem had occured (even when I had safely shut it down). A few times the drive actually became corrupted in some way, such that all of the permissions changed and I had to reset the permissions on the drive to access it.

I've also found that one solution to the problem is to replace the HDD with the old optical drive, go into bios, boot into a windows install disk, shutdown, replace HDD, and reboot. (This has worked twice but maybe it was just coincidence?)

I assumed this was due to a dodgy drive, so about a month ago I replaced the drive with a brand new 1TB hdd. But the problem didn't stop. Since then, I've reinstalled Windows from fresh, replaced the HDD caddy and updated my BIOS.

What is unusual is that the drive shows up in BIOS but not in Windows (not even in disk manager). This problem seems to happen randomly with not prompting.

The only thing I can possibly imagine now is either some deep-seated software issue or something dodgy in the Sata circuitry.

Can anyone suggest any possible causes or solutions? This is driving me nuts and I'm scared that I will loose all of my data.

Comment: Is there a hard drive to mobo cable? Try replacing that.

Comment: There is. I had a look just now and it looks ok. I unplugged and replugged it. Furthermore, once I booted up, it no longer recognised the HDD. Again, plugging in the original optical drive instead of the HDD, booting from a windows 8 install disk, shutting down, replacing the HDD and booting fixed the solution.

Comment: This makes me think it seems a lot like a software issue? But a very strange one

Comment: Back up your data...

Comment: Of course I am, but it's not really a long term solution when all of my data is being corrupted every few days